# Get kubernetes service running on specific port

Tags: service, kubernetes, minikube

How to set k8s service on port 80:

trying:

```
λ kubectl run hello-nginx --image=nginx --port=80
deployment "hello-nginx" created

λ kubectl expose deployment hello-nginx --type=LoadBalancer
service "hello-nginx" exposed

λ kubectl get services
NAME          CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
hello-nginx   10.0.0.142   <pending>     80:30674/TCP   12m
kubernetes    10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        1h

λ minikube service hello-nginx --url
http://192.168.178.105:30674
```

Is it possible to expose this service at http://192.168.178.105:80 ?

Environment: Windowns 10, Docker with Hyper-V

Answer (score 0):

You are using the LoadBalancer strategy, that is recommended when you are using a cloud environment.

You should check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address-service/) doc to expose ports in your nodes directly this way:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-nginx --type=NodePort
```

After that you can check the port assigned to expose your service and you should be able to access to it.

The range of ports that kubernetes use with this strategy can be configured as you can see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/) with the "--service-node-port-range portRange" atribute. By default it will use a random port in a range 30000-32767
You can choose the port assigned from the range configured, but I'm not sure right now if you can configure that range to use privileged ports.

If you can't and need to expose your app with the port 80, the easiest solution is to use an nginx to proxypass from port 80 to your-service-nodeport